# Linq Entry( entity.Related ).Query.Load() not writing back to Collection property

Tags: entity-framework, linq, loading

Supposing I have three EF entity classes:

```
public class Person {
    ...
    public ICollection Vehicles { get; set; }
}

public class Vehicle {
    ...
    public Person Owner { get; set; }

    public CarModel ModelInfo { get; set; }
}

public class CarModel {
    ...
    // properties for make, model, color, etc
}
```

The `Person.Vehicles` property is lazy-loaded.

Supposing I have a `Person` instance already loaded and I want to load its `Vehicle` collection property such that it also includes the related `ModelInfo` property.

So I have this:

```
void LoadVehiclesAndRelated(MyDbContext dbContext, Person person)
{
    dbContext.Entry( person )
        .Collection( p => p.Vehicles )
        .Query()
        .Include( v => v.ModelInfo )
        .Load();
}
```

Used like so:

```
using( MyDbContext dbContext = ... ) {

    Person p = GetPerson( 123 );

    LoadVehiclesAndRelated( dbContext, p );
}

foreach(Vehicle v in p.Vehicles) {
    Console.WriteLine( v.ModelInfo );
}
```

However when I do this, I get an exception at runtime when it first evaluates the `p.Vehicles` expression because the property is actually empty (so it wants to load it) but the DbContext is now disposed.

When the `.Load()` call was made (inside `LoadVehiclesAndRelated()` I saw the SQL being executed against the server (in SQL Server Profiler) but the collection property remains empty.

How can I then load the property and with the `Include`d sub-properties?

Annoyingly, this scenario is not mentioned in the MSDN guide for explicit-loading: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: Just for clarity, the `dbContext` variable inside the `LoadVehiclesAndRelated` is the same as the enclosing `using( MyDbContext context = ...`?

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes - I'll add clarification to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like calling `.Query().Load()` is not the same as calling `DbCollectionEntry.Load` directly, and the important difference is that the former does not set the [`IsLoaded`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbCollectionEntry%602.IsLoaded);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) property, which then is causing triggering lazy load later. Most likely because as explained in the link, the former is intended to be used for filtered (partial) collection load scenarios.

Shortly, to fix the issue, just set `IsLoaded` to true after loading the collection:

```
var entry = dbContext.Entry(person);
var vehicleCollection = entry.Collection(p => p.Vehicles);
vehicleCollection.Query()
    .Include( v => v.ModelInfo )
    .Load();
vehicleCollection.IsLoaded = true;
```

P.S. For the sake of correctness, this behavior is sort of mentioned at the end of the **Applying filters when explicitly loading related entities** section:

> When using the Query method it is usually best to turn off lazy loading for the navigation property. This is because otherwise the entire collection may get loaded automatically by the lazy loading mechanism either before or after the filtered query has been executed.